Scale-specific or scale specific? (Compound Modifiers)
Which one is correct?

Scale-specific process
Scale specific process

Is there are rule regarding the use of the hyphen?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Almost certainly a duplicate, see e.g. 1 2 3 4 but you need to provide a complete sentence, as it depends on the details.

Welcome to ELU. The practice here is to include in one’s post evidence that you’ve tried to answer your question before posting it. Where have you looked? What did you find? And a real requirement for receiving a useful, correct answer is to provide enough context for others to fully understand the situation that you are asking about.

In the absence of further information, the linked question and the reference in its answer appears to answer this one. If it doesn't, please edit the question further to add more detail.

If it's intended to be a compound word, then it must be hyphenated. Otherwise, it's a syntactic construction. It looks like a compound adjective so, yes, it should be hyphenated.
